# Tomcat 7 doesn't change the cert store using server.xml file

Tags: certificate, tomcat7, keystore, server.xml

after server rebuild we have install a own certificate in a server with CentOS 6.x and tomcat7 and it  it works but showing in navigation address bar a red cross indicating chrome doesn't trust in us, logically. This certificate was installed in certstore01 key store.

keytool -list -keystore certstore01 -storepass pass4certstore01

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

mkyong, Aug 25, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:X:XX

Afther that we have re-key  acquired certificate from GoDaddy and we have installed the chain without problem:

keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore certstore02 -alias root -file gdroot-g2_cross.crt -storepass pass4certstore02

keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore certstore02 -alias intermed -file gdig2.crt -storepass pass4certstore02

keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore certstore02 -alias latiendamiga.com -file myIssuedCertByCA.crt -storepass pass4certstore02

and it is showed perfectly:

keytool -list -keystore certstore02 -storepass pass4certstore02

keytool -list -keystore csltndmg -storepass cgr7hd9qgah6g0qgg33

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

root, Sep 5, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:...
latiendamiga.com, Sep 5, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:...
intermed, Sep 5, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): XX:XX:...

then we have change the server.xml file from

keystoreFile="/path4certstore/certstore01"
keystorePass="pass4certstore01"

to

keystoreFile="/path4certstore/certstore02"
keystorePass="pass4certstore02"

and it stop to work, I mean it work wit the first server.xml configuration but not with the second one.

Could somebody help me at this point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work probably because Key password doesn't match with keystore one.

As I can see in Tomcat documentation 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore

under Configuration / Prepare the Certificate Keystore section, if key password and keystore don't match both must be set in server.xml file, but I'm not able to see how I must to configure server.xml file for both password.

Could somebody help me at this point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kainix, sorry to bother you. I feel stupid, I have the following configuration in server.xml : <Connector 
   port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
   keystoreFile="/home/eatjadmin/mykeystorefile"
   keystorePass="keystorepassword" 
   keyPass="keypassword"
  />
   but it doesn't work, could you help at this point?